# setting width of div jquery

Tags: jquery, html, coding-style, width

I'm trying to set the width of a div using jquery.

this is how I'm trying to set the size of the div

```
$('#page').css("width",data[0]['imageWidth']);
```

and this is the div I'm trying to set

```
<div id="page">
 </div>
```

any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: What is this data[0]['imageWidth']?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSS lengths require a unit, in this case most likely Pixel (`px`):

```
$('#page').css("width",data[0]['imageWidth'] + "px");
```

Comment: Try to log what `data[0]['imageWidth']` contains and make sure it's correct.

Comment: @rahul: Only if the browser has a bug.